# line.new() draws only for current month and not drawn on previous months

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I attempted to draw the highest and lowest price lines of the first 2 days of the month for every month using line() function as follows:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Highest and lowerest lines of the first 2 days of month", overlay = true)

var float hh = na
var float ll = na
var int days_elapsed = na
var int x1 = na
new_month = ta.change(month) != 0
new_day = ta.change(dayofmonth) != 0

if new_month
    hh := high
    ll := low

    days_elapsed := 1
    x1 := bar_index
if new_day and not new_month
    days_elapsed += 1

if days_elapsed <= 2
    hh := math.max(hh, high)
    ll := math.min(ll, low)

bgcolor(new_month ? color.yellow : na)
line.new(x1, hh, bar_index, hh, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.green)
line.new(x1, ll, bar_index, ll, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red)
```

However, when run, it only draws the lines for the current month and not for previous months. How can I fix this problem so that it will draw the lines for all of the months in the displayed time frame?

[High and low for the first 2 days of the month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ukG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the lines using a `var` variable and then it will save the previous lines. You will also want to use if statements to set your x2 variables. The way you currently have it, will draw a new line every new bar so you won't be able to see much history due to the max_line limit.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Highest and lowerest lines of the first 2 days of month", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)
var line hLine = na
var line lLine = na
var float hh = na
var float ll = na
var int days_elapsed = na
var int x1 = na
new_month = ta.change(month) != 0
new_day = ta.change(dayofmonth) != 0

bgcolor(new_month ? color.yellow : na)
if new_month
    hh := high
    ll := low
    days_elapsed := 1
    x1 := bar_index

    hLine := line.new(x1, hh, bar_index, hh, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.green)
    lLine := line.new(x1, ll, bar_index, ll, xloc = xloc.bar_index, color = color.red)

if new_day and not new_month
    days_elapsed += 1

if days_elapsed <= 2
    hh := math.max(hh, high)
    ll := math.min(ll, low)
    hLine.set_y1(hh), hLine.set_y2(hh)
    lLine.set_y1(ll), lLine.set_y2(ll)

if bar_index > bar_index[1] and not new_month
    hLine.set_x2(bar_index), lLine.set_x2(bar_index)
```